# How do I partition my Xubuntu install to maximize my small hard drive?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, 18.10, partitioning

I'm installing Xubuntu on a laptop with a 32GB SSD. I want to have my /root partition be the largest possible size. Letting the installer configure partitions automatically leaves a portion of the hard drive unused as "unallocated space" and other partitions oversized so I want to learn how to partition manually and maximize available hard drive space to keep my programs and files. I just want to know which partitions are necessary for installation, flags, etc.

Comment: I would not partition at all.

Comment: On a 32G SSD, I would let Xubuntu do the partitioning. You don't have the room to do this yourself and be successful.